# Downloading file from homepage without url. Using java

Tags: java, url, download

I need to be able to download a file from a webpage using Java. The problem is that i can't seem to find the exact URL for the file. Example: www.something.com/file.xls.

The file i need can be find on this url: http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/aktier/Historiska_kurser/?Instrument=SSE837#divId
You can see the Excel-logo if you scroll down a bit.

Would be glad if anyone have a library that might be able to help me with this and also of course any other type of guidance in my problem :)

Comment: The problem is that they're not using a simple <a> tag to download the file.  The Excel logo is in a simple <div> tag, which means they probably use Javascript to detect when you click on it and download it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no general solution to your problem -- JavaScript can be used to obfuscate what is and is not a link and where the link goes.  If you're interested in scraping a specific page, though, you may be able to reverse-engineer it.

On the page you linked, for example, the Excel logo has ID `exportExcel`.  Searching for `#exportExcel` eventually leads to this code fragment:

```
if(to.match(/^\d{4}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2}$/) && from.match(/^\d{4}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2}$/)) {
    var query = webCore.createQuery( webCore.marketAction.getDataSeries, {}, {
            FromDate: from,
            ToDate: to,
            Instrument: webCore.getInstrument(),
            hi__a : "0,1,2,4,21,8,10,11,12,9",
            OmitNoTrade: "true",
            ext_xslt_lang: currentLanguage,
            ext_xslt_options: "," + $("#adjustedId:checked").val() + ",", //$("#unadjustedId:checked").val() + ",",
            ext_xslt: "hi_table_shares_adjusted.xsl",
            ext_contenttype : "application/ms-excel",
            ext_contenttypefilename : "_" + webCore.getInstrument() + ".xls",
            ext_xslt_hiddenattrs: ",ip,iv,",
            ext_xslt_tableId: "historicalTable"
        }
    );
    $("#excelQuery").val( query );
    $("#excelForm").attr( "action", webCore.proxyURL ).submit();
}
```

That's building a URL with some sort of hidden form submission.  By experimenting and tracing through source code, you should be able to replicate what it's doing in your Java code to generate the URL you want.  You'll need some familiarity with JavaScript and JQuery.

Another method is to click the download link while watching your network traffic (via [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) for example) and observe the constructed URL that your browser is requesting. You'll need some knowledge of HTTP.

Comment: Thanks Nathaniel. I thought it would require a solution similar to what you said. Just couldn't find the JS-code that was relevant. Will try to trace it first to the constructed URL.